# Bulk multi rename tool

Tags: linux, shell

I need a live multi rename tool.
The one you can find in double commander, or even better total commander.
The best I could find is renameutils, 
which lists all the files and let me edit them in my favorite text editor, 
but nothing beats something which is designed to be specifically used to rename.

Is there such a program?
Has to be live and interactive - I have to see the edits I'm doing before hitting the "OK" key.
Has to be in the command line - ncurses, slang, shell. Just not GUI.

---

Edit:
It's probably doesn't belong here, but super-user:)
Answers would still be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about RenameWand? http://renamewand.sourceforge.net/

But you indeed should have tried superuser instead: https://superuser.com/questions/25378/mass-renaming-nix-version

Comment: It's a nice tool, but not a live edit. I'm looking for something more in the lines of PyRenamer, just for the command line...Anyway, closing this for now.

Comment: You can use Multi-Rename script. You can drive it via script. https://code.google.com/p/multi-rename-script/